# Web Scraping URL links in R when links are within .dialog-off-canvas-main-canvas

Tags: r, web-scraping, canvas, hyperlink

Long time lurker first time poster. I'm new to web scraping, and R, and have largely generated my code from stackoverflow and Youtube so I'm hoping someone can assist with a conundrum I'm having. Many thanks in advance.

Recently, I've been practicing scraping links. For the blog articles of Union of Concerned Scientists this went swell, see below, apologies for the inefficiencies, I'm new.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(stringr)

UCS_blog_links = data.frame()

for(page_result in seq(from = 1, to = 3, by = 1)) {
  link = paste0("https://blog.ucsusa.org/page/",page_result)
  page = read_html(link)
  url_links = page%>% html_nodes(".post-thumbnail") %>%
    html_attr("href")
  UCS_blog_links = rbind(UCS_blog_links, data.frame(url_links, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))%>%
    distinct()
  print(paste("Page:", page_result))
}
```

BUT when I try this same method on the Union of Concerned Scientists [Press Releases](https://www.ucsusa.org/about/news/press-releases) the links are not on the main page, they are "behind" .dialog-off-canvas-main-canvas so I was wondering if anyone had any tips to modify the code I have to first go into the node .dialog-off-canvas-main-canvas and then scrape the links. Or if another method is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the links by,

```
url = 'https://www.ucsusa.org/about/news/press-releases' %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('.view-content') %>% html_nodes('a') %>% html_attr('href')
url = unique(url)

 [1] "/about/news/experts-tell-epa-follow-science-protect-communities-ethylene-oxide"                      
 [2] "/about/news/new-sec-rule-vital-transparent-accounting-mounting-climate-risks-businesses-protecting-1"
 [3] "/about/news/union-concerned-scientists-applauds-repeal-trump-era-agency-action-scrapping-californias"
 [4] "/about/news/proposed-epa-truck-pollution-standard-falls-short-whats-needed-healthier-safer-future"
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Such a simple solution.